# How to comment out LaTeX code in Gedit?

Tags: gedit, block-comment

I am not sure if it is supported but cannot find it.

OS: Debian 8.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's supported by the [code comment plugin](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/ShippedPlugins) ([`gedit-plugins`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/gedit-plugins) in Debian). Make sure it's installed, then in the gedit preferences, enable "Code Comment" in the "Plugins" tab. Open a TeX or LaTeX document, select some text, and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> to comment the corresponding lines. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> uncomments.

Comment: This abbreviation is not intuitive at all. There is also no menu view of all Gedit keybindings which make them hard for me to remember. It would be ok if there would be any or documentation in the program interface itself. - - How have you tried to resolve the issue which I describe?

Comment: I'm not sure what issue you're describing... It would be nice if the shortcuts pane was updated depending on what plugins were active, yes. But the editor does come with built-in documentation, accessible from the interface, which lists these shortcuts: open the main menu, then "Help", scroll down to "gedit Plugins", click on "Configure and use gedit plugins", scroll down until you find "Code comment", and click on that to see the plugin's documentation. (I haven't checked the version in Debian 8, things might be different there...)

Comment: I hope the developers will note the problem with Gedit's usability and extensions. The addon's keybindings should update to shortcuts pane.